# How to connect Minikube windows 10 connect to local cassandra DB

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cassandra-2.0, minikube

I have insatlled Below Softwares in windows 10

1.cassandra version 2.2.15

2. Docker version  19.03.2

3.minikube version: v1.4.0

4.helm client and sever v2.15.0-rc.1

5. kubectl client  v1.14.6 and server  v1.16.0

I am running cassandra DB in localhost port 9042 , i want to connect that localhost DB to my minikube helm  with the IPaddress or hostname of the cassandra i am not able .

Comment: Which driver was used to run `minikube`? Could you provide your configuration YAMLs? Cassandra was deployed inside Minikube Cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to connect to the local cassandra db to Minikube cluster , need to change the 
rpc_address in cassandra.yaml

`rpc_address: <LOCAL_WINDOWS_IPV4_ADDR>

 broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4`